# Rails will paginate table with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table, admin, will-paginate

I'm building a small admin page for my app that will display data from 4 models in one table. The columns are: Clubs, Users, Posts, Comments.

A club has_many users, a user has_many posts and has_many comments.
So my questions is do I need to add pagination explicitly to each of my 4 models in my admin_controller? The way it is now, I get the page list on the top and bottom of my table, and I can go back and forward pages, but all of my results are shown on the first page (~9000 results).

In my admin_controller I have

```
 @clubs = Club.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 50)
```

and in my view

```
<%= will_paginate @clubs %>
<table>
<% i = 0 %>
<tr class="new-admin-top-row">
  <td><%= "Club Location" %></td>
  <td>| <%= "Number of Signups "%> </td>
  <td>| <%= "Number of Posts By Users"%>    </td>
  <td>| <%="Number of Comments By Users"%> </td>
</tr>
    <%= @clubs.find_each do |club| %>
        <tr class="new-admin-row">
          <td class="new-admin-cell"><%= club.name %></td>
          <td class="new-admin-cell f"><%= @users_array[i] %></td>
          <td class="new-admin-cell s"><%= @posts_array[i] %></td>
          <td class="new-admin-cell"><%= @comments_array[i] %></td>
          <td class="new-admin-cell"><%= @elevates_array[i] %></td>
        <% i+=1 %>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @clubs %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find_each` method works on ActiveRecord::Relation objects and fetches 1000 records in batches. So that is where you problem most likely is. Change it to `each` and it'll probably solve your issue.

You can read more about `find_each` here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Now, however, my page shows the raw text of the table, unformatted, above the table itself. So I have all of the data twice on each page, once just as a massive string, and then again in the table where I want it. Any ideas? [i would just hide the div, but the raw data isn't any div, it just shows up]

Comment: That's because `each` returns the object in the end. So you should remove the `=` sign in `<%= @clubs.each`